# C++ Pointers in function parameters

Tags: c++

If I declare a function:

```
vector<int> & call(string *target)
```

How should I use target in the function for a comparison with another string? For example:

```
string str;
if(str == //string in target){
...
}
```

As `&target`, or simply `target`?  Also, how should the return look? I'm assuming it should be:

```
return &some_vector;
```

since that is the type in the function declaration.  Finally, what about the opposite? That is:

```
vector<int> & call(string &target)
```

When in the function and wanting to use the string, is it as simple as:

```
*target
```

Comment: Please read a beginner C++ tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your first question it's

```
if(str == *target){
```

On your second question my advice would simply be, don't. It looks like you are trying to return a reference to a local variable. That is a well known newbie mistake that will simply crash your program.

On your third question it's

```
if(str == target){
```

Comment: Just so I'm sure on this you're saying if the function declaration has

    &target

as a parameter, then 

    if(str == *target)

works?

Thank you for an answer to the last part. My code was indeed crashing

Comment: No, not that at all. Sorry for the confusion. Initially I missed your third question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dereference the pointer to get the object. That is, use `*`:

```
if (str == *target) {
```

> Also, how should the return look?

You're returning a reference, not a pointer. That means you simply need to return the name of the object:

```
return some_vector;
```

> Finally, what about the opposite?

If `target` is a reference (NOT a pointer) than you simply use the name of the object. There's no dereference involved with this.